# Github Actions workflow fails when running steps in a container

Tags: docker, github-actions

I've just started setting up a Github-actions workflow for one of project.I attempted to run the workflow steps inside a container with this workflow definition:

```
  name: TMT-Charts-CI

  on:
    push:
      branches:
        - master
        - actions-ci

  jobs:
    build:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      container:
        image: docker://alpine/helm:2.13.0

      steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Validate and Upload Chart to Chart Museum
        run: |
          echo "Hello, world!"
          export PAGER=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD)
          echo "Changed Components are  => $PAGER"
          export COMPONENT="NOTSET"
          for CHANGE in $PAGER; do ENV_DIR=${CHANGE%%/*}; done
          for CHANGE in $PAGER; do if [[ "$CHANGE" != .* ]] && [[ "$ENV_DIR" == "${CHANGE%%/*}" ]]; then export COMPONENT="$CHANGE"; elif [[ "$CHANGE" == .* ]]; then echo "Not a Valid Dir for Helm Chart" ; else echo "Only one component per PR should be changed" && exit 1; fi; done
          if [ "$COMPONENT" == "NOTSET" ]; then echo "No component is changed!" && exit 1;  fi
          echo "Initializing Component => $COMPONENT"
          echo $COMPONENT | cut -f1 -d"/"
          export COMPONENT_DIR="${COMPONENT%%/*}"
          echo "Changed Dir => $COMPONENT_DIR"
          cd $COMPONENT_DIR
          echo "Install Helm and Upload Chart If Exists"
          curl -L https://git.io/get_helm.sh | bash
          helm init --client-only
```

But Workflow fails stating the container stopped due immediately.

[image: Error Description]

I have tried many images including "alpine:3.8" image described in official documentation, but container stops.

According to [Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps), in the Container section: "A container to run any steps in a job that don't already specify a container." My assumption is that the container would be started and the steps would be run inside the Docker container.

Comment: Container is stopped or can't start. Seem there is no image `docker://alpine/helm:2.13.0` to pull and start it

Comment: Image is pulled and container starts for once, but then stops immediately

Comment: It picks image from dockerhub

Comment: I just try to pull your container.Then I get this `docker pull docker://alpine/helm:2.13.0                              
     invalid reference format`

Comment: Seem github can't pull your image and start it. If you get this image from dockerhub, and it public, why I can't pull it ? And image name clearly invalid format

Comment: Its github actions syntax to append docker:// before image name, read this https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps

Comment: I just take a look on their example. And `my_job:
    container:
      image: node:10.16-jessie` I meen, seem there is no need to add docker://

Comment: It can be done without docker:// prefix but issue remains same, it doesnt matter if u put "docker://" or not cause in logs in shows that image is pulled and container is started, I cant attach sc here, but image is pulled and container is started.

Comment: You see, screenshot says that container is not running, that means container is there but its stopped, and obviously container was started from image provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this my making custom docker images, Actually Github runners somehow stops the running container after executing the entrypoint command, I made docker image with entrypoint the make container alive, so container doesn't die after start.

Here is the custom Dockerfile (https://github.com/rizwan937/Helm-Image)
You can publish this image to dockerhub and use it in workflow file like

```
 container:
   image: docker://rizwan937/helm
```

You can add this entrypoint to any docker image so that It remains alive for further steps execution.

This is a temporary solution, if anyone have better one, let me know.